# Need a more elegant way of finding an element in the dom tree with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few elements flying around in an element that need to be altered when the window finishes loading (`$(window).load...`)

When the script loads, I've been struggling to find a more elegant way of finding a string.

Noticeably below, you can also see the rampant re-use of `parent` and `next` operators...

I've tried `closest` but it only goes up the dom tree once (from what I understand) and `parents` has never really worked for me, but I could be using it wrong.

Ex.

```
$(window).load( function(){
    if($(".postmetadata:contains('Vancity Buzz')").length){
        $(this).parent().parent().next().next().next().next('.articleImageThumb img').hide();
    }
});
```

HTML output this runs through looks like this:

```
<div class="boxy">
    <div class="read">  
        <div class="postmetadata">Vancity Buzz</div>
        <div class="articleTitle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightCtrls"></div>
    <div class="initialPostLoad"></div>
    <div class="ajaxBoxLoadSource"></div>
    <div class="articleImageThumb">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="image.png" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt=""/>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your `$(this)` refers to the window

Comment: `parents()` won't magically not work just for you. it will do exactly what the manual says it will do, every time. try reading the manual and making sure you know how it works. then you will know if you should use it here or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
$(".postmetadata:contains('Vancity Buzz')")
     .closest('.read') //Closest will get you to the parent with class .read
     .siblings('.articleImageThumb').hide(); //this will get you all the siblings with class articleImageThumb
```

`this` refers to window there not the element you are checking in the if condition.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8n4w/)**

I don't know if your intention is to have the empty anchor tag just by hiding the image. if so just add a find to it.

Comment: @canacast there are many ways to do it. check @:prodigitalson answer too.

Comment: @canacast by the way you want to hide the image alone leaving the anchor tag empty?

Comment: @PSL Good question, and not quite. `hide` was just a placeholder. I still need to figure out how to change the `src="..."` path to represent a different site to get larger article images and avoid tiny innocuous RSS thumbnails.

Comment: @PSL BINGO AGAIN! No wonder you have thousands of points! I hope you get showered with gifts for your good deeds.

Comment: @PSL great fiddle btw! Any ideas how I'd change only a portion of the href `src`? I'm trying to use `.replace('something.com/thisdir/','something.com/thatdir/')` to no avail.

Comment: `.attr('href', function() { return this.replace('ex.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/', 'ex2.com/files/styles/article_main/public/')})` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @canacast this doesn't refer to the url in the function you need to use the 2nd argument. like this `.attr('src', function (_, curSrc) {
    return curSrc.replace("http://THIS-NEEDS-TO-CHANGE/", 'http://placehold.it/100x100')
});`  Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N3CE8/

Comment: @PSL Amazing, again! Haven't seen the documentation for `curSrc` before. Any reference url?

Comment: @canacast yes it is there syntax is `.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )` ref: http://api.jquery.com/attr/.

Answer (score 4):

You can just do this

```
$('.articleImageThumb img').toggle($(".postmetadata:contains('Vancity Buzz')").length)
```

If there are multiple divs and you do need to traverse then there are multiple ways

```
$(".boxy:has(.postmetadata:contains('Vancity Buzz'))").find('.articleImageThumb img').hide()
```

or

```
$('.postmetadata:contains("Vancity Buzz")').closest('.boxy').find('.articleImageThumb img').hide()
```

or

```
$(".boxy:has(.postmetadata:contains('Vancity Buzz')) .articleImageThumb img").hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into parents http://api.jquery.com/parents/ you can pass a selector like so:

```
 $(this).parents('.boxy').find(".articleImageThumb")
```

Careful though, If there is a parent boxy to that boxy, parents() will return it and thus you find multiple .articleImageThumb.